# how much size's to give a button in android?

Tags: android

in my application  i used the designed image for Buttons. how to give a size for  images for three drawable hdpi,mdpi and ldpi? how to give width & height size for buttons?

Comment: You can upload and generate your icons here. It will generate for different dpi and different version of android. http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to declare your button size.

Use http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html to know how big to make it.

Answer (score 0):

this is size of for all layouts of device.

```
1.hdpi= 480X800
2.mdpi= 320X480
3.ldpi= 240X320
```

Image button size is not , its depend on how design is require ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio guideline stated here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Example:

If you have a 100x100 pixel image in mdpi folder, then you should have:

- 75x75 in ldpi folder
- 150x150 in hdpi folder
- 200x200 in xhdpi folder